# navbar icons position issue

Tags: html, css

How to set the icon right next to the navbar text?

Code:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#" id="other-color" class="ui-btn ui-shadow ui-btn-icon-left ui-custom-icon ui-arrow ui-nodisc-icon">Set Filter</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" id="other-color" class="ui-btn ui-shadow ui-btn-icon-right ui-custom-icon ui-location ui-nodisc-icon">Add Page</a></
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
.ui-arrow:after {
    content: '';
    background-image: url(icons/filled-filter-32.png);
    background-size: 15px 15px;
}

.ui-location:after {
    content: '';
    background-image: url(img/plus-32.png);
    background-size: 15px 20px;
}
```

[image]

I need like this, before and after the text I don't need the space.

[image]

Comment: The css code you provided isn't enough to answer your question. Also the links have 6 classes and two of them (ui-btn-icon-left, ui-btn-icon-right) seem to be responsible for the layout. Did you try removing them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add image before:

```
a.ui-arrow{ 
   display: inline-block;
   padding-left: 25px;
}
```

To add image after:

```
a.ui-location{ 
   display: inline-block;
   padding-right: 25px;
}
```

Manage the padding as per your background image